# R - creating a linear model with fixed poly() coefficients

Tags: r, distribution, lm, polynomials

In R, one can build an `lm()` or `glm()` object with fixed coefficients, using the `offset` parameter in a formula.

```
x=seq(1,100)
y=x^2+3*x+7
# Forcing to fit the polynomial: 2x^2 + 4x + 8 
fixed_model = lm(y ~ 0 + offset(8 + 4*x + 2*I(x^2) ))
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using `poly()`? I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
fixed_model_w_poly <- lm(y ~ 0 + offset(poly(x, order=2, raw = TRUE, coefs= c(8, 4, 2))))
```

> Error : number of offsets is 200, should equal 100 (number of observations)

I want to use `poly()` as a convenient interface to run iterations with a high number of fixed coefficients or order values, rather than having to manually code: `offset(8 + 4*x + 2*I(x^2) )` for each order/coefficient combination.

---

P.S: **Further but not essential information**: This is to go inside an MCMC routine. So an example usage would be to generate (and then compare) `model_current` to `model_next` in the below code:

```
library(MASS)
coeffs_current <- c(8, 4, 2)
model_current <- lm(y ~ 0 + offset(poly(x, order=2, raw = TRUE, coefs= coeffs_current )))
cov <- diag(rep(1,3))
coeffs_next <- mvrnorm(1, mu = as.numeric(coeffs_current ),
                       Sigma = cov ) 
model_next <- lm(y ~ 0 + offset(poly(x, order=2, raw = TRUE, coeffs_next ))
```

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty in accessing  `fixed_model$residuals`

Comment: @BondedDust, I edited the question to clarify. That is not the problem. I am trying to create fixed models using `poly()`, where I can easily feed in the fixed coefficients and the order I want, rather than manually having to write `offset(8 + 4*x + 2*I(x^2) ))` in the formula.

Comment: Offer an example for how you expect the coefficients to come into this process. After looking at the help page and structure of the `poly(.)`-result I'm unclear how to proceed, so I'm thinking a more automated approach to building a formula with the desired offsets would be easier. (As long as you are using the residuals, I think you should be safe from the pitfalls associated with not using `poly()`.

Comment: @ BondedDust, I have added a simplified usage example to the bottom of the question - in reality `model_current` and `model_next` symbolise my current and proposed models, respectively, in a Markov Chain Monte Carlo routine.

Comment: I dont understand.. The code and the data are all included in the question, they are runnable as is. You do not need any further information, specific data to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates what I suggested. (*Not* to use poly.)

```
library(MASS)
# coeffs_current <- c(8, 4, 2) Name change for compactness.
cc <- c(8, 4, 2)
form <- as.formula(bquote(y~x+offset(.(cc[1])+x*.(cc[2])+.(cc[3])*I(x^2) )))
model_current <- lm(form, data=dat))
```

I really have no idea what you intend to do with this next code. Looks like you want something based on the inputs to the prior function, but doesn't look like you want it based on the results.

```
cov <- diag(rep(1,3))
coeffs_next <- mvrnorm(1, mu = as.numeric(cc ),
                       Sigma = cov )
```

The code works (at least as I intended) with a simple test case. The bquote function substitutes values into expressions (well actually calls) and the as.formula function evaluates its argument and then dresses the result up as a proper `formula`-object.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20), y=rnorm(20) )
cc <- c(8, 4, 2)
form <- as.formula( bquote(y~x+offset(.(cc[1])+x*.(cc[2])+.(cc[3])*I(x^2) )))
model_current <- lm(form, data=dat)
#--------
> model_current

Call:
lm(formula = form, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     -9.372       -5.326    # Bizarre results due to the offset.
#--------
form
#y ~ x + offset(8 + x * 4 + 2 * I(x^2))
```

Comment: Should be possible to repeat the second step in a loop or pass to into `replicate` if you did the random variate draw prior to the formula construction.

Comment: Thanks again, @BondedDust. Am I right that I can use the same bquote method, mixed with rep()to generate polynomial equations with varying orders? ( not just 2)

Comment: I don't see why not. It's just expression-text inside bquote. It does get parsed so it needs to be `parse()`-able: This succeeds: `bquote( poly(x, degree=.(cc[1]) )  )`. I'm not sure about `rep` though. That's not the same function as `replicate`.

Comment: I think I am close but  did not manage to get  it right, this gives the correct structure: `replicate(length(cc), paste('cc[[',i,']]*I(x^',i, ') + ', sep=''))` apart from the excess `+` in the end. Do I have to use a form of `apply` to increment `i`?

Comment: When I suggested `replicate` I was assuming you would have a random number generation step inside the set of expressions that would be `replicate()`-ed. You seem to be doing that generation outside and in that instance replicate is not the right choice for a control structure.